# JSF context from Servlet

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

I have a JSF2 controller/bean/view that is invoked the standard JSF way. Now I have a need to access this logic from a legacy part of the app that knows servlets and URL params only.

I thought of creating a "loader.xhtm" view that bridges the gap between non-jsf requester and the jsf part of the app. Loader will take URL params and make the necessary JSF post to backing bean. etc. One downside of this approach is - it's one extra client/server hop, a programmatic redirect. However it is simple to implement.

But is there a more clever way? I found someone who created servlet filter and explicitly created a [FacesContext](http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf-java/please-tell-your-developers-to-call-facescontextrelease/), started the lifecycle and the ViewRoot. Conceptually I see what is being done, but I don't know how to put it into practice. Has anyone interfaced with JSF lifecycle directly from a servlet? Do you have a sample?

[Another](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Access+FacesContext+From+Servlet) mention of this concept.

Comment: JSF is just an abstraction on top of basic servlet API. There's nothing impossible in plain servlet what's possible in JSF itself. It'd be better if you elaborate what exactly do you need the `FacesContext` all for (i.e. which of its methods are you interested in, etc), then we can tell you the plain servlet ways to achieve exactly that.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. My navigation between 2 JSF views is like so: Page1 does action="#{controller.setupAndForward}, it passes parameters during the postback. setupAndForward() does its thing and forwards to next view, it returns "Page2". It passes a bean in request scope, which is then picked up in the following controller and elevated into a custom view scope. Page2 is a full jsf/richfaces page with lots of ajax.  Now, I want to reuse that code to access it from a legacy JSP that has links to a servlet which I have control of.